# Maven found missing in Eclipse IDE (Mars) after installing m2e-egit

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2e

unable to create a maven project after installing the m2e-egit plugin; Obviously I don't see the maven option under **Eclipse > Window > preferences**

[image]
[image]

**Tool used:**

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?, I have same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue but after installing m2eclipse-scala, not m2eclipse-egit.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

*Firstly, for Maven*:
**Eclipse > Help > Install new software** and add **http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases**.

*Secondly, for m2e-egit*: 
**Eclipse > Help > Install new software** and add
**https://repository.takari.io/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/LATEST/**.
Because the version of m2e-egit in the Marketplace is outdated

Now restart eclipse.

It perfectly worked for me (Mars Version).

Comment: Thanks for the links.. will try them :)

Comment: Maven is not available in Eclipse even after installing the plugin http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.:(

Comment: Ok, I dont see why. So ... you can 1) reinstall eclipse to see if it's just a bug, or 2) check if you can "convert to maven project" in Eclipse > Right click on the project > configure > "convert to ... " , or 3) install maven separately. You will be able to execute maven command line. The advantage is the compilation is three times faster than in eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, eclipse reinstallation is the only fix for this. However this seems to be a bug in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with m2eclipse-scala.  I tracked the issue down to what seems to be multiple installs of the m2e plugin, one explicit and one implicit.  This plugin gets installed by m2eclipse-scala if it's not already there (perhaps similarly to how m2e-egit operates).  The base version of Eclipse that I'm using does NOT show m2e installed under Window > Installation Details, but all of the Maven buttons and toolbars are already present, and explicitly installing m2e makes them disappear.

Comment: In my case it was some other connector plugin which got installed while project import.